# Seeking details of AssemblyRef use in source of ASP.NET Repeater Control

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Reviewing the web Repeater control in the Microsoft Reference Source there's an identifier for `AssemblyRef` as such: [`AssemblyRef.SystemDesign` on line 22](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/UI/WebControls/Repeater.cs#0ba7b95bc1b1a6cf#references) however I cannot drill into it using the source viewer tool and there seems to be no `using` that would cause it to be recognized by the compiler.

Basically what is this identifier, why is it there and how is it used in program without breaking compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an `internal static` class with no namespace.

The Reference Source site lists several copies of the file, although it doesn't show one under `System.Web`. However, all of the files appear to be empty.

The class contains a series of constants, so the compiled code won't include any reference to the class; it will just contain the value of the constant.

It's quite easy to see the content of the class using a decent decompiler. The .NET 4.5.1 version from `System.Web` contains:

```
using System;

internal static class AssemblyRef
{
    internal const string ASPBrowserCapsFactory = "ASP.BrowserCapsFactory, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b7bd7678b977bd8f";
    internal const string ASPBrowserCapsPublicKey = "b7bd7678b977bd8f";
    internal const string EcmaPublicKey = "b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string EcmaPublicKeyFull = "00000000000000000400000000000000";
    internal const string EcmaPublicKeyToken = "b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string MicrosoftJScript = "Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string MicrosoftPublicKey = "b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string MicrosoftPublicKeyFull = "002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010007D1FA57C4AED9F0A32E84AA0FAEFD0DE9E8FD6AEC8F87FB03766C834C99921EB23BE79AD9D5DCC1DD9AD236132102900B723CF980957FC4E177108FC607774F29E8320E92EA05ECE4E821C0A5EFE8F1645C4C0C93C1AB99285D622CAA652C1DFAD63D745D6F2DE5F17E5EAF0FC4963D261C8A12436518206DC093344D5AD293";
    internal const string MicrosoftPublicKeyToken = "b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string MicrosoftVisualStudio = "Microsoft.VisualStudio, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string MicrosoftVisualStudioWeb = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string MicrosoftVisualStudioWindowsForms = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string MicrosoftVSDesigner = "Microsoft.VSDesigner, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string MicrosoftVSDesignerMobile = "Microsoft.VSDesigner.Mobile, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string MicrosoftWebDesign = "Microsoft.Web.Design.Client, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string Mscorlib = "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string PlatformPublicKey = "b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string PlatformPublicKeyFull = "00000000000000000400000000000000";
    internal const string PlatformPublicKeyToken = "b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string SharedLibPublicKey = "31bf3856ad364e35";
    internal const string SharedLibPublicKeyFull = "0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100B5FC90E7027F67871E773A8FDE8938C81DD402BA65B9201D60593E96C492651E889CC13F1415EBB53FAC1131AE0BD333C5EE6021672D9718EA31A8AEBD0DA0072F25D87DBA6FC90FFD598ED4DA35E44C398C454307E8E33B8426143DAEC9F596836F97C8F74750E5975C64E2189F45DEF46B2A2B1247ADC3652BF5C308055DA9";
    internal const string SharedLibPublicKeyToken = "31bf3856ad364e35";
    internal const string SilverlightPlatformPublicKey = "7cec85d7bea7798e";
    internal const string SilverlightPlatformPublicKeyFull = "00240000048000009400000006020000002400005253413100040000010001008D56C76F9E8649383049F383C44BE0EC204181822A6C31CF5EB7EF486944D032188EA1D3920763712CCB12D75FB77E9811149E6148E5D32FBAAB37611C1878DDC19E20EF135D0CB2CFF2BFEC3D115810C3D9069638FE4BE215DBF795861920E5AB6F7DB2E2CEEF136AC23D5DD2BF031700AEC232F6C6B1C785B4305C123B37AB";
    internal const string SilverlightPlatformPublicKeyToken = "7cec85d7bea7798e";
    internal const string SilverlightPublicKey = "31bf3856ad364e35";
    internal const string SilverlightPublicKeyFull = "0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100B5FC90E7027F67871E773A8FDE8938C81DD402BA65B9201D60593E96C492651E889CC13F1415EBB53FAC1131AE0BD333C5EE6021672D9718EA31A8AEBD0DA0072F25D87DBA6FC90FFD598ED4DA35E44C398C454307E8E33B8426143DAEC9F596836F97C8F74750E5975C64E2189F45DEF46B2A2B1247ADC3652BF5C308055DA9";
    internal const string SilverlightPublicKeyToken = "31bf3856ad364e35";
    internal const string System = "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string SystemComponentModelDataAnnotations = "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35";
    internal const string SystemConfiguration = "System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemConfigurationInstall = "System.Configuration.Install, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemCore = "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string SystemData = "System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string SystemDataOracleClient = "System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string SystemDeployment = "System.Deployment, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemDesign = "System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemDirectoryServices = "System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemDrawing = "System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemDrawingDesign = "System.Drawing.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemEnterpriseServices = "System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemManagement = "System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemMessaging = "System.Messaging, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemNetHttp = "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemNetHttpWebRequest = "System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemNumerics = "System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string SystemRuntimeRemoting = "System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string SystemRuntimeSerializationFormattersSoap = "System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemRuntimeWindowsRuntime = "System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string SystemRuntimeWindowsRuntimeUIXaml = "System.Runtime.WindowsRuntimeUIXaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string SystemSecurity = "System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemServiceModelWeb = "System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35";
    internal const string SystemServiceProcess = "System.ServiceProcess, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemThreadingTasksDataflow = "System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string SystemWeb = "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemWebAbstractions = "System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35";
    internal const string SystemWebDynamicData = "System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35";
    internal const string SystemWebDynamicDataDesign = "System.Web.DynamicData.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35";
    internal const string SystemWebEntityDesign = "System.Web.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string SystemWebExtensions = "System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35";
    internal const string SystemWebExtensionsDesign = "System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35";
    internal const string SystemWebMobile = "System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemWebRegularExpressions = "System.Web.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemWebRouting = "System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35";
    internal const string SystemWebServices = "System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string SystemWindowsForms = "System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string SystemXml = "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
    internal const string VJSharpCodeProvider = "VJSharpCodeProvider, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a";
    internal const string WindowsBase = "WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35";
}
```

Comment: the hero everybody needs, deserve and love. thnx